# How to use Selenium with aliased Python 3

Tags: 14.04, python-2.7, python3

I have recently moved on to Ubuntu 14.04, which has both Python 2 (2.7.6) and Python 3(3.4.0) installed by default. For writing test scripts, I have Selenium installed.

If I use the aliasing method to make default python command to point it to Python 3,    it doesn't recognizes Selenium and returns error

```
zac@zac:~$ alias python=python3
zac@zac:~$ cd Documents
zac@zac:~/Documents$ cd SelPython
zac@zac:~/Documents/SelPython$ python dropdown2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "dropdown2.py", line 2, in <module>
from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: No module named 'selenium'
```

If I revert back to Python 2, I am able to run these perfectly fine.

How do I enable Python 3 to recognize Selenium?

Comment: How to setup Selenium with Python: http://blog.testproject.io/2016/11/23/using-selenium-with-python-tutorial-p1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python2 and Python3 should be treated as entirely seperate entities and not be intermixed. Python3 cannot use Python2's libraries, and vice versa.

You need to install Selenium under Python 3.

```
sudo pip3 install -U selenium
```

Also note that `alias python=python3` is not a good idea!

Comment: Ok. So how do you propose I do that?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a suggestion.

Comment: As soon as I saw your answer, I tried installing Selenium again, but using pip, which told me that I had the latest Selenium again. I was not aware of this pip3 thing. New thing learned. Thank You.